# asp.net WebForms & asp.net MVC security options

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

What are the options for implementing secure login on a website and ensuring that the website itself as a whole is secure? - for both asp.net and mvc......

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the prepared winforms accounting in asp.net mvc template. Then you can use the [Authorize] attribute infront every action you want to prevent from accessing before logging in.